# QuickBooks Customer query response

Tags: xml, vb.net, quickbooks

I'm not an XML expert, this is the problem I'm trying to solve. I get this XML response form QuickBooks when I run a query for a list of customers, as you can see in the node `<CustomerRet>` the children nodes are not always the same, I already tried using xmlDocument to get the values from the children nodes `<FullName>` and `<CreditLimit>`, and I get an error when I try to read the node `<CreditLimit>` since is not on all `<CustomerRet>` instances.

Is there a way to know when a node is not present and continue to the next customer? or is there a way to query quick books for just those two fields, customer name and credit limit?

This is the request:

```
  Private Shared Function GenerateXmlRequest_CustomerQuery()

    Dim sbRequest As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    sbRequest.Append("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>")
    sbRequest.Append("<?qbxml version=""" & ClsCommon.GetQBVersion + """?>")
    sbRequest.Append("<QBXML>")
    sbRequest.Append("<QBXMLMsgsRq onError=""continueOnError"">")
    sbRequest.Append("<CustomerQueryRq requestID = ""0"">")
    sbRequest.Append("<ActiveStatus >ActiveOnly</ActiveStatus>")
    sbRequest.Append("</CustomerQueryRq>")
    sbRequest.Append("</QBXMLMsgsRq>")
    sbRequest.Append("</QBXML>")
    Return sbRequest.ToString()
End Function
```

Here's the response:

```XML
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRs>
      <CustomerQueryRs requestID="0" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
         <CustomerRet>
            <ListID>800002FB-1556242302</ListID>
            <TimeCreated>2019-04-25T20:31:42-06:00</TimeCreated>
            <TimeModified>2019-06-24T15:13:21-06:00</TimeModified>
            <EditSequence>1556242302</EditSequence>
            <Name>Company A</Name>
            <FullName>Company A</FullName>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            <Sublevel>0</Sublevel>
            <Balance>1245.00</Balance>
            <TotalBalance>1245.00</TotalBalance>
            <JobStatus>None</JobStatus>
            <PreferredDeliveryMethod>Email</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
         </CustomerRet>
         <CustomerRet>
            <ListID>800002F4-1554669899</ListID>
            <TimeCreated>2019-04-07T15:44:59-06:00</TimeCreated>
            <TimeModified>2019-09-16T12:15:42-06:00</TimeModified>
            <EditSequence>1568654142</EditSequence>
            <Name>Company B</Name>
            <FullName>Company B</FullName>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            <Sublevel>0</Sublevel>
            <CompanyName>Company B</CompanyName>
            <BillAddress>
               <Addr1>Company B</Addr1>
            </BillAddress>
            <BillAddressBlock>
               <Addr1>Company B</Addr1>
            </BillAddressBlock>
            <Balance>0.00</Balance>
            <TotalBalance>0.00</TotalBalance>
            <SalesTaxCodeRef>
               <ListID>80000002-1544571801</ListID>
               <FullName>Company B</FullName>
            </SalesTaxCodeRef>
            <CreditLimit>8000.00</CreditLimit>
            <JobStatus>None</JobStatus>
            <PreferredDeliveryMethod>Email</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
         </CustomerRet>
         <CustomerRet>
            <ListID>800002F6-1555095868</ListID>
            <TimeCreated>2019-04-12T14:04:28-06:00</TimeCreated>
            <TimeModified>2019-04-12T14:04:28-06:00</TimeModified>
            <EditSequence>1555095868</EditSequence>
            <Name>Company C</Name>
            <FullName>Company C</FullName>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            <Sublevel>0</Sublevel>
            <Balance>0.00</Balance>
            <TotalBalance>0.00</TotalBalance>
            <JobStatus>None</JobStatus>
            <PreferredDeliveryMethod>Email</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
         </CustomerRet>
         <CustomerRet>
            <ListID>800002F7-1555096260</ListID>
            <TimeCreated>2019-04-12T14:11:00-06:00</TimeCreated>
            <TimeModified>2019-09-16T12:15:30-06:00</TimeModified>
            <EditSequence>1568654130</EditSequence>
            <Name>Company D</Name>
            <FullName>Company D</FullName>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            <ParentRef>
               <ListID>800002F6-1555095868</ListID>
               <FullName>Company D</FullName>
            </ParentRef>
            <Sublevel>1</Sublevel>
            <Balance>0.00</Balance>
            <TotalBalance>0.00</TotalBalance>
            <CreditLimit>2000.00</CreditLimit>
            <JobStatus>None</JobStatus>
            <PreferredDeliveryMethod>Email</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
         </CustomerRet>
      </CustomerQueryRs>
   </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

Comment: It's hard to know how this question garnered an answer, since many of the tags in the question were obscured by not being surrounded with backticks. Please always use the preview window to see if your question will be rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xml Serizlization.  Empty items will be null

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME)

        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(QBXML))

        Dim qbxml As QBXML = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class QBXML
    <XmlArray("QBXMLMsgsRs")>
    <XmlArrayItem("CustomerQueryRs")>
    Public CustomerQueryRs As List(Of CustomerQueryRs)
End Class
Public Class CustomerQueryRs
    <XmlAttribute()>
    Public requestID As Integer
    <XmlAttribute()>
    Public statusCode As Integer
    <XmlAttribute("statusSeverity")>
    Public statusSeverity As String
    <XmlAttribute("statusMessage")>
    Public statusMessage As String

    <XmlElement()>
    Public CustomerRet As List(Of CustomerRet)

End Class
Public Class CustomerRet
    Public ListID As String
    Public TimeCreated As DateTime
    Public TimeModified As DateTime
    Public EditSequence As String
    Public Name As String
    Public FullName As String
    Public IsActive As Boolean
    Public Sublevel As Integer
    Public Balance As Decimal
    Public TotalBalance As Decimal
    Public JobStatus As String
    Public PreferredDeliveryMethod As String
    Public CompanyName As String
    Public CreditLimit As Decimal

    <XmlElement("BillAddress")>
    Public BillAddress As List(Of BillAddress)

    <XmlElement("BillAddressBlock")>
    Public BillAddressBlock As List(Of BillAddress)

    Public SalesTaxCodeRef As CodeRef
    Public ParentRef As CodeRef
End Class
Public Class BillAddress
    Public Addr1 As String
End Class
Public Class CodeRef
    Public ListID As String
    Public FullName As String
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks jdweng, I finally understood how that works.